# unrelated code in switch case, no compiler warning/error

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I found some very special code and wonder why it compiles. Inside a `switch` some code is placed not related to any `case`. See below:

```
int main()
{   
    for ( auto i: { 1,2,3,4})
         {   

             switch ( i ) 
             {   
                 case 1:
                     std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
                     break;

                 case 2:
                     std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
                     break;

                     {
                         std::cout << "What is the sense of this part?" << std::endl;
                     }

                 case 3:
                     std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
                     break;

                 default:
                     std::cout << "default" << std::endl;
                     break;
             }
         }
}
```

gcc (8.3.1) complains only with the warning:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:56:81: warning: this statement may fall through [-Wimplicit-fallthrough=]
                      std::cout << "What is the sense of this part?" << std::end
main.cpp:59:18: note: here
              case 3:
```

clang (7.0.1) did not tell anything, even with `-pedantic -Wextra -Wall`.

I wonder why both compilers accept that code. The generated executable will never execute it, which is the good thing :-)

Is it legal c++ code?

Comment: `break;` can happen anywhere in the `case` clause. You find it often conditional (in an `if` clause) Therefore it's legal code. But gcc can issue a diagnostic message it if detects (a) unreachable code or (b) code what could cause a fall through.

Comment: Non-reachable code is still legal code.

Comment: No issue with the code. generally these thing will be found in static code analysis of project.

Answer (score 0):

It is a legal code. You can remove `break` or put it anywhere in the `case`.

> The [break](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch) statement, when encountered in statement exits the switch
>   statement

Comment: It is not about the break, it is about the code block not related to any case

Comment: @Klaus break doesn't mean the case is finished. It's finished when the next case came in.

Comment: What else? switch(...) ... case x: ... beak; case y: ... break; What else means break? Sorry, that confuses me!

Comment: @Klaus break just means exit the switch. See the link there are examples with no break.

Comment: A switch statement will check each case until one passes, and then execute subsequent lines of code unconditionally until the switch block ends or a `break` statement is hit. There is nothing special about the format of the statement that would make that free standing code block in the middle illegal.

Comment: @Klaycon But there might be a general semantic rule that unreachable code is illegal. There isn't in C++, but there might be. It doesn't have to relate specifically to the syntax of this statement.

Comment: there may be case statements with no break. read on control statements more carefully.